# Geo-location added to standard custom google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add geo-location to a custom public google map, I can't manage to get it to work. [For example here is a custom public google map](https://maps.google.ca/maps/ms?msa=0&msid=202458571791405992786.0004b9061a3fcd9461d42).

Lets say I wanted to add geo-targeting to that map. I have the following on the site which is directly off the google maps API website:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>
```

as well as the following which I just changed '.getElementsById' to '.getElementsByClassName':

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
      });

      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

Then I call for the map which is in a lightbox:

```
<a href="https://maps.google.ca/maps/ms?msa=0&msid=202458571791405992786.0004b9061a3fcd9461d42&lightbox[width]=70p&lightbox[height]=70p" class="map-canvas lightbox"><h2 class="dis">Where can I<br />get Rumble?</h2></a>
```

It displays the map fine, and asks to geo-target but I assume the reason its not working on this map is because its not included in the API.

I was hoping someone had a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://maps.google.ca/maps/ms?msa=0&msid=202458571791405992786.0004b9061a3fcd9461d42) is not an API based map.  You can display the KML from that map on an [API based map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linkto.html?filename=https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.ca%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fie%3DUTF8%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dkml%26msid%3D202458571791405992786.0004b9061a3fcd9461d42)

Then use your geolocation code to center the map (depending on the ordering, you might need to use the preserveViewport:true option on the KmlLayer).  Relevant code below, see the [documenation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers) for more examples and information.

This is in your existing page (leave your version)

```
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
```

Add this to display the data from your "custom map":

```
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer("https://maps.google.ca/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=202458571791405992786.0004b9061a3fcd9461d42");
kmlLayer.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Sorry in advance for this question, but I have no idea why the map is not even showing in the first place. 

I have copied the code from this page here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

Into a blank HTML doc and I dont even see the map? I think were all sorted other then that issue. Again thanks for all the help.

Comment: Your question is a [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[google-maps-api-3]+default.css).  Did you copy the [default.css](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css) file a local directory, link to the absolute URL of that file (not a good idea in production, but OK for a quick test) or include the equivalent css inline? (the map needs to have a size, or you can't see it)

Comment: Yes I have it added as an internal stylesheet into the head of the doc. Strange. You can see the map so far here: http://drinkrumble.com/rumble_fr/test.html

Comment: I get an error on that page (left out the quotes around the URL string, fixed the answer to include them) `Error: missing ) after argument list
Source File: http://drinkrumble.com/rumble_fr/test.html
Line: 41, Column: 47
Source Code:
  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(https://maps.google.ca/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=202458571791405992786.0004b9061a3fcd9461d42);`

Comment: Thanks added that but still not getting a map, sorry for this.

Comment: The id of your map div is "map_canvas", your code is looking for "map-canvas", they aren't the same...

Comment: As I mentioned in my original answer, you may need to set the preserveViewport:true option on the KmlLayer, it will prevent the KmlLayer from zooming to fit its content, see the documentation.

Comment: One thing thats diving me nuts is the icon size for some reason is tiny...I have no idea why the icons are so much smaller when doing it this method?

Comment: You could try [geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.ca%2Fmaps%2Fms%3Fie%3DUTF8%26msa%3D0%26output%3Dkml%26msid%3D202458571791405992786.0004b9061a3fcd9461d42), what browser are you using.

Comment: I am in Chrome...you can see on my link http://drinkrumble.com/rumble_fr/test.html that the icons are much smaller then on the actual map https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=210000746142049190989.0004ce14b7a8e95167602&msa=0&lightbox[width]=70p&lightbox[height]=70p which is strange. I tried using the API methods for icon size but it has no effet.